# Threading a function with powershell and using the results within the same script

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a script that connects to all servers in our domain. The script then loops through each server to get the local administrators and nested members of the groups and places them into a PSObject so that I can export the PSObject to CSV later.

Now I am confused about how to call a function using start-job passing a paramter, and also being able to utilise the output from that function within my existing script.

So let's assume i do the following:

```
function addnumbers{
param([int]$a, [int]$b)
[int]$c = $a + $b
$myobj = new-object PSObject
$myobj += $c
return $myobj
}

$exportdetail = @()

[int[]]$numbers = @(1,2,3,4)

foreach ($number in $numbers)
{
   $newobj = new-object PSObject
   $newobj = addnumbers $number
   $exportdetail += $newobj        
}

 $exportdetail | export-csv -notype "c:\export.csv"
```

Now to thread the loop I would do the following:

```
    function addnumbers{
param([int]$a, [int]$b)
[int]$c = $a + $b
$myobj = new-object PSObject
$myobj += $c
return $myobj
}

$exportdetail = @()

[int[]]$numbers = @(1,2,3,4)

foreach ($number in $numbers)
{
   $ScriptBlock {
   param($num)
   $newobj = new-object PSObject
   $newobj = addnumbers $num
   }
   start-job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $number
   $exportdetail += $newobj        
}

 $exportdetail | export-csv -notype "c:\export.csv"
```

Will those object be updated into the exportdetail overall object?

When I run the code the individual threads kick off but they don't return any data.

Answer (score 0):

From the help: `Start-Job returns an object that represents the job that it started.`
This means you don't get results from Start-Job, only a reference to the job which holds the results.

So, to get to the results, you have to receive the job (where the results are stored) like this:

```
    $job = start-job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $number
    $exportdetail += $job
}
Wait-Job $exportdetail
Receive-Job $exportdetail | export-csv -notype "c:\export.csv"
```

Basically, you create a background job for each number, then add the reference to the job into an array of jobs.  At the end, you wait for all the jobs to finish, and then receive the results.